# Use value of token list at time of \keys_set:nn

Tags: expl3, xparse, l3keys

I'm trying to set up a macro `\MyCommand{#1}{#2}` which takes two inputs, one being a key-val list and then creates a token list which is named based on the input and the key name, having the value given to that key as the contents of the token list.

My attempt so far is to use `l3keys` as follows, with the contents of `#1` stored in some `\l__dai_temp_tl` along with `.tl_set:c = { l_dai_ \tl_use:N \l__dai_temp_tl _tl }` however this appears to use the value of `\l__dai_temp_tl` at the point of `\keys_define:nn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__dai_temp_tl

\keys_define:nn { daikeys } {
    foo .tl_set:c = { l_dai_ \tl_use:N \l__dai_temp_tl _tl },
}

\NewDocumentCommand \MyCommand { m  m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__dai_temp_tl { #1 }
    \keys_set:nn { daikeys } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\MyCommand{bar}{foo=foobar}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\l_dai_bar_tl
\l_dai__tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

In the above code `\l_dai__tl` has the value `foobar` while `\l_dai_bar_tl` is undefined, when I had hoped that this would (define and) set `\l_dai_bar_tl` to a value of `foobar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `.tl_set:c`. This is a variant of `.tl_set:N` which is therefore converted to a name *at the point of definition* rather than *at the point of use*. At definition, `\l__dai_temp_tl` is empty and so you get `\l_dai__tl` as you've observed.

If you want to create variables on-the-fly you will need to do it yourself

```
\keys_define:nn { daikeys } {
    foo .code:n =
     {
       \tl_clear_new:c { l_dai_ \tl_use:N \l__dai_temp_tl _tl }
       \tl_set:cn { l_dai_ \tl_use:N \l__dai_temp_tl _tl } {#1}
     },
}
```